# Unable to understand pip warning "pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper"

Tags: python, pip

Every time I run `pip` the below warning comes up.

> WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
> Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
> To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.

Please help me understand it.[Pip Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mdrw.png)

Edit 1. I tried reinstalling pip, but the Warning persists. Also, I am attaching the snip for the additional warning I got when I reinstalled the pip.

WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.8.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\shash\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

[Warning while re-installing pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XJR8.png)

Comment: Well, did you check the linked issue? Did you use ``python -m pip`` instead, and did it fix the issue?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes running pip commands with python -m pip does remove this warning. And I am also able to install any package without adding the m flag. I just want to understand what's causing this warning and how can I remove this.

Answer (score -2):

*WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.1; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\vignesh.rajendran\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.*

To get rid of this warning you should upgrade pip using,

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

After pip upgrade also you will get the Deprecation message as python 3.5 is in the end of its Life, Please upgrade to the latest python

*DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.*

Comment: @Spooky What warning you are getting?